# Is "Indirect Overriding" of static methods possible in Java?

Tags: inheritance, methods, static, overriding, non-static

We can't override a static method (at least in Java).

If I want to override an inherited static method, can I do it via a nested call to a non-static method of the parent class which I have overriden?

```
class A {
.
.
static func(args) {..M(args)..}
.
.
<Type> M(args) {...}
.
.
}

class B extends A {
.
.
@Override
<Type> M(args) {...}
.
.
}
```

Or, will this code be able to change the functionality of `func`?

Comment: Overloading static methods is certainly possible, and overriding isn't possible -- you have them switched.  But even so, this is best addressed by just writing the code for what you want to try and seeing what happens, or at least sharing specific code instead of a description of code.

Comment: Right, just show us the code you want to try.  Basically you have to implement each method from scratch here, there's no way to "automatically" refer to a static method.  That's why they're "static."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where it breaks:

> I have defined the static method of A with the help of a nested call
> to M.

You can’t call a non-static method from a static method.

If I understand you correctly, you wanted to do something like:

```
public class A {
    public static void staticMethod() {
        m();
    }
    public void m() {
        // do something here or leave it to the subclasses
    }
}
```

In my Eclipse, at the call to `m()` I get

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method m() from the type A

To call a non-static method you need an instance to call it on. For example, to ask a person’s name you first need a person object, or the question won’t make sense. In a static context you haven’t got any instance.

Of course, if you can set up a situation where inside `staticMethod` you have got an instance of either `B` or `C`, you’re there. Then you can just call `myInstanceOfBOrC.m()`.

The usual solution to what I think you were after is to make an instance of either `B` or `C` from the outset and not declare the method static. Then use usual overriding. It may feel like a waste to create an instance for this purpose alone; but it works.

Comment: I meant 'override'. Sorry for the mix-up. Anyways, I get your point. Thanks for the quick clarification, and sorry for the ridiculous question.

Comment: No, the question is fine. We’re all hitting that wall at some point and thinking about whether there is a way to obtain what you were asking. The question could easily be helpful for other readers too.